# spreadsheets - service error - getlastcolumn

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Nothing changed for many days in my spreadsheet. Currently while trying to execute function, even simple `getlastcolumn()` I am receiving a service error. What is strange is this error is only in my spreadsheet. I can copy code and paste it in a different spreadsheet and it will work.

I've discovered that changing style and merge cells have the same effect - service error with no details. Sometimes data deletion helps and even undo this action is resolving problem for some time.

Do you have any idea what the problem is?

I use sample code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// This logs the value in the very last cell of this sheet
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow, lastColumn);
Logger.log(lastCell.getValue());
```

This code works in a regular spreadsheet but not in my Duplicating spreadsheet.

Example of solving problem temporary:

Delete data from spreadsheet - no error.
Undo deletion - no error.
Insert row - no error.
Delete inserted row - error appeared.
Delete data - no error.
Undo deletion - no error.
Insert row - no error.
Delete inserted row - error appeared again.

Maybe this can be a clue.

Comment: What do you see in View -> Execution transcript?

Comment: [19-02-22 06:03:47:288 PST] Rozpoczynam realizację
[19-02-22 06:03:47:302 PST] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 s]
[19-02-22 06:03:47:386 PST] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Roadmap]) [0,083 s]
[19-02-22 06:03:47:611 PST] Sheet.getLastColumn() [0,224 s]
[19-02-22 06:03:47:620 PST] Realizacja nie powiodła się: Service error: Spreadsheets (wiersz 36, plik „Code”) [całkowity czas: 0,311 sekund]

Comment: 'Service error: Spreadsheets' usually means you are making a lot of API calls. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) before you call the getLastColumn() method. If it starts working then the next step will be to refactor your code to make less API calls whenever possible but that suggestion is a wild guess and could probably be erroneous.

Comment: I am still having problem. :(

Comment: How big is this spreadsheet (total number of cells)? How complex? Is this the only code in your project? What do you usually do before this code executes? Where is the code for those steps?

Comment: I am sorry for delay in my response. Here is my answer. 
In demo sheet when error can be reproduce there is many columns up to BK.

I can share this demo spreedsheet with some google account if this could be usefull. :)

Comment: I have the same issue my code.  It works 99.5% of the time but throws the "Service Error" in two different places of the code where I use getLastColumn(). The code is running via a one minute timed trigger.